# Convert column name symbol using the for loop or r function in r

Tags: r

I want to convert the variable names dot(.) symbol to underscore ( _ ) symbol using the loop or any r base function

```
df <- data.frame("abc"= c('a','b','c'),"b3.01" =  1:3, "b3.02"= 1:3, "b3.04"= 1:3,"b7.01" = 1:3, "b7.02"= 1:3, "b7.03"= 1:3)
```

Tell me which code i run to rearrange my variable name, like as b3_01, b3_01, b7_01 ect.

Comment: `names(df) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(df))`

Comment: As pointed out in the comments in linked post, try `chartr()`

Answer (score 0):

```
df <- data.frame(a.1 = 1:4,
                 b.2 = 11:14,
                 c.3 = 111:114)

df

  a.1 b.2 c.3
1   1  11 111
2   2  12 112
3   3  13 113
4   4  14 114
```

Use `gsub` to replace the literal dot with an underscore.

```
names(df) <- gsub("\\.", "_", names(df))

names(df)
```

Is now:

```
[1] "a_1" "b_2" "c_3"
```

And

```
df <- df[, c("c_3", "b_2", "a_1")]
```

Brings `df` in this form:

```
  c_3 b_2 a_1
1 111  11   1
2 112  12   2
3 113  13   3
4 114  14   4
```

Comment: Maybe set `fixed = TRUE` for efficiency.